# Energy dissipated during cycle of damping force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, resonance, dissipation

Considering a drive damped oscillator after transients have died out and is being drive close to resonance such that $\omega=\omega_0$, I want to find the energy dissipated during one cycle, $\Delta E_{dis}$. My current steps are as follows:

Without transients, my motion is modeled by $x(t) = A \cos{(\omega t-\delta)}$, so $\dot{x}=-A\omega \sin{(\omega t - \delta)}$

Damping force is given by $F_{dmp} \cdot v=bv \cdot v$, where $\frac{b}{m}=2 \beta$

Then our energy can be given by

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Delta E_{dis} = \int F_{dmp}v\, dt\ &= \int_0^\tau -2m \beta A^2\omega^2\sin^2{(\omega t-\delta)}\, dt\\ 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Note: $\sin^2{x}=\frac{1-\cos{2x}}{2}$

So,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Delta E_{dis} &=  -2m \beta A^2\omega^2 \int_0^\tau \frac{1-\cos{(2\omega t-2\delta)}}{2}\, dt\\ 
&=-m\beta A^2 \omega^2[t+\frac{1}{2\omega}\sin{(2\omega t-2\delta)}] \mid_{t=0,\tau}\\
&=-m\beta A^2 \omega^2[\tau+\frac{1}{2\omega}\sin{(2\omega \tau-2\delta)}-\frac{1}{2\omega}\sin{(-\delta)}]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

How do I further simplify this equation? I'm not entirely sure how to get rid of my trig functions here, as I'm supposed to show that $\Delta E_{dis} = 2\pi m \beta \omega A^2$

Comment: Use the relation $\omega \times \tau = 2 \pi$, by the definition of a period $\tau = 2\pi / \omega$.

Comment: My apologies for the late response, I ended up using that and it got me a bit further along. About 20 minutes later, I remembered to use the trig identity $\sin{(2n\pi - \theta)} = \sin{(\theta)}$. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome. Often we forgot the most funcdamental stuffs.